# Joins in the Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The firebase data structure is

```
{
  "eventAttendees" : {
    "fm" : {
      "1" : "David",
      "2" : "Alice"

    }
  },
  "events" : {
    "fm" : {
      "date" : "2017-06-16",
      "name" : "Firebase Meetup"
    },
    "gm" : {
      "date" : "2017-08-12",
      "name" : "Meet Linh"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "1" : {
      "email" : "david@gmail.com",
      "name" : "David"
    },
    "2" : {
      "email" : "alice@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Alice"
    },
    "10" : {
      "email" : "khanh@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Khanh"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to find all users who go to fm event. Here is my code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("eventAttendees/fm").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
           print (snapshot.key)
            ref.child("users/\(snapshot.key)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (userSnapshot) in
                let content = userSnapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
                print(content)
            })
        })
```

I follow this tutorial https://youtu.be/Idu9EJPSxiY?t=3m14s ,

Base on the tutorial `snapshot.key` should return "1", "2", so that `ref.child("users/\(snapshot.key)")` will be `ref.child("users/1")`

But on my code, the `snapshot.key`return "fm", and `ref.child("users/\(snapshot.key)")` will be `ref.child("users/fm")`

Where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `eventAttendees/fm` you have multiple children. So you will need to loop over those child nodes in your code too:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("eventAttendees/fm").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        print (child.key)
        ref.child("users/\(child.key)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (userSnapshot) in
            let content = userSnapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            print(content["name"])
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It is strange that in the video tutorial, the author does not have to loop. Did I miss something?

Comment: In the video David uses `on("child_added"` for the outer loop, which fires a separate event for each child. You use `on("value"`, which fires a single event for all matching children. That means you need to loop in the callback function.